# How does vendor/assets stylesheet find vendor/img images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Bbootstrap.css is inside vendor/assets/stylesheets/ and inside bootstrap.css, there's this line,

```
dropdown-submenu:focus > a > [class*=" icon-"] {
  background-image: url("../images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
}
```

However, my ruby on rails app is complaining

```
GET http://localhost:3000/images/glyphicons_halflings-white.svg 404 (Not found)
```

How do I get it found? glyphicons_halflings-white.svg is inside vendor/assets/img

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `image-url` inside your stylesheet and Rails will ensure the proper path is used. If you don't use that helper, you will have nothing but broken images in production when asset fingerprinting is employed.

In this case, the correct URL is `/assets/glyphicons_halflings-white.svg`. Again, though, that will not be the case in production.

Comment: this solution works! However I've 10 .css, does this mean I've to carefully see each .css and update it accordingly? This isn't good for long term as my .css are from my vendor and whenever they come out with a new version, I've to do the same thing which is quite tedious.

Comment: @SteveNg You don't have to use the asset pipeline to serve your images. You can also disable it entirely if it doesn't work for you. It sounds like you shouldn't be using this CSS in your `app` folder anyways, and if you're a developer you could easily whip up something to upconvert non-asset-pipeline CSS to work with it, or keep this “vendor css” in a gem to isolate it from your application.